# Can custom maps in Starcraft 2 automatically enable certain unit upgrades?

Tags: maps, modding, starcraft-2

If I create a custom map with the Starcraft 2 map editor, how can I specify that some unit upgrades are already researched?

For example, if I want all the units to already have the weapons upgrade 1 at the beginning of the game, can I specify this in the editor?

I've looked through the menus but didn't find anything that looked like it would relate to unit upgrades.

Comment: by the way, if you find the answer, I encourage you to add an answer here (to your own question) since the two answers as of right now are not really answers, and it would help other people like yourself in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable upgrades or set other special properties for a map you have to use a trigger that is executed at the start of the game.

In the map editor, `Modules -> Triggers (F6)` opens the trigger editor:

[image: Triggers window]

The only default trigger is "Melee Initialization", which is executed at the start of the game. New actions can be added to this trigger by choosing `New -> New Action (Ctrl-R)` in the right pane's context menu. Searching for "upgrade" brings up the correct action to add:

[image: Actions window]

Double-clicking on `Upgrade: (No Value)` then shows a window that lets you choose which upgrade you want to enable for the player.

The action created this way will be executed at the start of the game and enable the selected upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Since I don't have the editor at hand at the moment I can't answer you accurately... I can however tell you with some confidence that YES it is possible.

I have used the Warcraft III editor extensively, and I know there's a way to do this in that editor. There is no reason for it not being possible in the SC2 editor.

Look under the upgrades section and see if you can find a field called starting value or something. I know there's some section where you can define the starting value of your upgrades, and the maximum number of upgrades of that type.

Sorry I can't give you anything more specific.

Comment: Someone sure is fast on the downvote button...
I tried to offer a nudge for sth to go back and look again. In War3 there was a pr. player setting for all of the upgrades. I hardly think this has changed.

Comment: "I think there's something in a menu somewhere because I saw it in a semi-related game" is a bad answer, even if you are trying to be helpful.

Comment: Semi related game? It's still made by the same people, on the base of the war3 editor. It's not like I'm comparing UnrealEd with the Crysis editor.

Comment: That the same company made two games from the same codebase (eight years separated) does not make your answer good. It just makes it more likely that your _guess_ is correct. It's still not useful, and it's still a guess.

Comment: Put yourself in the guy who asks the question's shoes.

You write a question.
Nobody answers for 10 hrs.
Somebody gives a half assed answer(me) that makes you go into your editor and look again.
You find the damn thing.

Comment: Then I come back to my question, write a good answer explaining where it is, and accept my own answer.

Comment: I already guessed myself that it should be possible somehow, it just isn't obvious at all where you find anything related to upgrades in the editor. Especially there is not "upgrades section" nor anything about "starting values" of any kind.